# jquery single slide handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a HTML page with an ordinary jquery slider from jquery 1.12.1
But the slider has 2 handles and I can't manage to find the line of code that generates two handles. I've deleted the "values [x,y]" part in the script on my html, but it still gives two handles.
I think this is the JavaScript that generates it, but I'm not familiar with JS, so

```
    _createHandles: function() {
    var i, handleCount,
        options = this.options,
        existingHandles = this.element.find( ".ui-slider-handle" ),
        handle = "<span tabindex='0'></span>",
        handles = [];

    handleCount = ( options.values && options.values.length ) || 1;

    if ( existingHandles.length > handleCount ) {
        existingHandles.slice( handleCount ).remove();
        existingHandles = existingHandles.slice( 0, handleCount );
    }

    for ( i = existingHandles.length; i < handleCount; i++ ) {
        handles.push( handle );
    }

    this.handles = existingHandles.add( $( handles.join( "" ) ).appendTo( this.element ) );

    this._addClass( this.handles, "ui-slider-handle", "ui-state-default" );

    this.handle = this.handles.eq( 0 );

    this.handles.each( function( i ) {
        $( this )
            .data( "ui-slider-handle-index", i )
            .attr( "tabIndex", 0 );
    } );
```

I think this is the piece that does something, but I can't understand it's variables; where they come from.

```
for ( i = existingHandles.length; i < handleCount; i++ ) {
        handles.push( handle );
    }
```

If somebody knows how to delete this piece of code whilst making the handle appear afterwards (I tried to delete different lines, but that didn't work), Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please show the code you use to initiate the slider eg `$( ".selector" ).slider({options});`

Comment: @iamalismith
`$( "#slider" ).slider({
 range: true, 
 value: [0]
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the `range: true` option.

When this is removed, you are left with a slider with only 1 handle.

> range: If set to true, the slider will detect if you have two handles
>   and create a styleable range element between these two.

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range

Also, if you only want one handle, you should probably just use the `value` property, instead of `values`.

http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value

```js
$(function(){

//creates 2 handles
$( ".example-a" ).slider({
   range: true,
   values: [0]
});

//creates 1 handle slider
$( ".example-b" ).slider({
  values: [0]
});

//also creates 1 handle slider
$( ".example-c" ).slider({
  value: 0
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 
 <h2>Example A - 2 handles<h2>
<div class="example-a"></div>

<h2>Example B - 1 handle (values)<h2>
<div class="example-b"></div>

<h2>Example C - 1 handle (value)<h2>
<div class="example-c"></div>
```

Comment: It may be caused by my themerolled UI, but it still does not work.

Comment: Okay, the JS had a line that said range:true; so I made it false and now it works! thank you, only thing that remains is to get it coloured again, because the spacing between the two handles contained a picture, that isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

That is a for loop that I believe creates a handle as long as i is less than the variable handleCount. You will need to change the variable handleCount so that the for loop only executes once, thus creating one handle.

something like:

```
handleCount = 1;
```

Comment: It does delete the handler, but now I'm unable to move it at all... gonna have to search for that.

Comment: I think that when making the handleCount =1; causes the slider to freeze, because it now is 1 and stays one. The line is some sort of equation. But again I'm not a JS pro

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so that's fixed, but one thing remains and that is that JS now searches for the other handle to create a colour in the spacing between the two.

```
if ( !this.range || !this.range.length ) {
            this.range = $( "<div>" )
                .appendTo( this.element );

            this._addClass( this.range, "ui-slider-range" );
        } else {
            this._removeClass( this.range, "ui-slider-range-min ui-slider-range-max" );

            // Handle range switching from true to min/max
            this.range.css( {
                "left": "",
                "bottom": ""
            } );
        }
        if ( options.range === "min" || options.range === "max" ) {
            this._addClass( this.range, "ui-slider-range-" + options.range );
        }
    } else {
        if ( this.range ) {
            this.range.remove();
        }
        this.range = null;
    }
},
```

Maybe this is something I have to rewrite. I don't know.

```
// Handle range switching from true to min/max
        this.range.css( {
            "left": "",
            "bottom": ""
```

Comment: Is this of any use?
`classes: {
   "ui-slider": "ui-corner-all",
   "ui-slider-handle": "ui-corner-all",

   // Note: ui-widget-header isn't the most fittingly semantic framework class for this
   // element, but worked best visually with a variety of themes
   "ui-slider-range": "ui-corner-all ui-widget-header"
  },`